# Can I edit the file app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php in laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm a beginner, and I have a stupid question, I really want to edit this file. Can I do this?

And when I update new Laravel version, is this file be replace by default?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can edit `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`. In fact, you are free to edit any files in the app directory. The app directory is never touched when you upgrade your Laravel version. You have to do any required upgrade-related changes manually.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

yes u can edit, then make all the update changes manually. And
 just make sure not to touch vendor folder.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also extend it and override what you need if we take into account some [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) principles:

> Open/Closed Principle or OCP states that software entities should be
>   open for extension, but closed for modification

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit only one folder - vendor

Comment: Thank you so much!